# How to load new url into a web view after a specific time duration?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an `array list` of a `model containing ---> key : { link : ... , duration : .... }`.
I need to load my android `web view` after through all the links present in my array list and load them for that `specific` duration.

**UPDATE**:

I tried handler and but it still loads the last web page and making Thread.sleep() hangs the app

Comment: Probably you need to observe the list to be empty or when all links are through. Can you please share  mode details?

Answer (score 1):

in a loop of array length limnitation, `i=0;i<=array.length();i++` , in there run a handler ,where set the duration value in delaytime.Before next handler start , stop the previous handler.

```
for(i=0;i<=array.length();i++)
{  handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
     new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //here set your code to load webview link from array list
                  webview.loadUrl(url[i]);


                }
            }, duration[i]); //set duration from array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use timerTask for specific interval to load your list urls

```
 private static Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        try {
            timer = new Timer();
            //initialize the TimerTask's job
            initializeTimerTask();

            //schedule the timer, to wake up every 2 second
            timer.schedule(timerTask, AppConstants.bgTaskStartDelay, 2000); //
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

 // it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            try {
               // you code here to load url from your array

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Tried but still the web view shows the last web page

Comment: show your code what you are doing and what you want

Comment: It worked. there was some missing endpoints from the API giving me the wrong list . Thaks It worked like a charm.